# Ways of distributing $10$ toys such that exactly $2$ children don't get any toy.

Tags: combinatorics

$10$ different toys are to be distributed among $10$ children.  Total no. of ways of distributing these toys such that exactly $2$ children do not get any toy is equal to?

My working: $10 \choose 2$ ways of choosing $2$ children who don't get toys and $10^8$ ways of distributing toys to $8$ children.
So total no. of ways $= {10 \choose 2} \cdot 10^8$

Answer given behind: $$(10!)^2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3!2!7!} + \frac{1}{2^46!}\right)$$
I have no idea whatsoever how to get here and whats wrong in my reasoning. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your method is wrong because you count cases in which $3$ or more kids don't get toys.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Poor two kids. Such an unfair distribution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First choose the boys who get nothing: $10\choose 2$.
Then, you have to distribute $10$ toys to $8$ boys, in such a way that each boy gets at least one. There will be either one boy with $3$ toys, either two boys with $2$ toys.

In the first case, choose the toys ($10\choose3$) and the boy ($8\choose1$), then distribute the $7$ remaining toys to the $7$ boys: $7!$.

In the second case, chose the first pair of toys and a boy (${10\choose2}{8\choose1}$) then the second pair and the second boy (${8\choose 2}{7\choose 1}$), but since you can exchange them, you count cases twice, so divide by $2$: $\frac12{10\choose2}{8\choose1}{8\choose2}{7\choose1}={10\choose2}{8\choose2}{8\choose2}$. Then there remains the $6$ toys given to $6$ boys, so $6!$ cases.

All in all, the number of cases is:

$${10\choose2}\left[{10\choose3}{8\choose1}7!+{10\choose2}{8\choose2}{8\choose2}6!\right]=1\textrm,360\textrm,800\textrm,000$$

---

To answer the comment: in the second case, you choose a first pair $\{A,B\}$ of toys, and a boy $X$ who will get it. Then you choose a second pair $\{C,D\}$ of toys among the remaining toys, and another boy $Y$ among the remaining $7$. But, among all such choices, there is one where the pair $\{C,D\}$ is chosen first, for the boy $Y$, and then the pair $\{A,B\}$ is chosen, for the boy $X$. Thus all choices appear twice in the possible outcomes, one in some order, one by exchanging them.

More generally, imagine that $k$ boys will get $p$ toys each. Then for all possible $(b_1,t_1),\dots,(b_k,t_k)$ (here $b_i$ denotes the boy, and $t_i$ the set of toys), any permutation of them also appears in the possible outcomes, though it's really the same combination of gifts. Hence you count them $k!$ each.

Comment: I didnt understand how are we counting the cases twice. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @Dèsjardins Updated. It's relatively tricky, so tell me if it's not clear enough.

Comment: I don't really get it.When we select the first pair of gifts we select from 10 gifts. Isn't that implicitly saying that we have chosen the first pair of gifts for the first kid? So even if we select the same pair again its now for the second kid and should be treated as a different case? Thanks for answering so quickly btw you're awesome :)

Comment: You are counting the number of possibilities, and you don't want to count them twice: if, from my way to separate distinct case, there are some which happen to be the same, it's bad. Here, if you choose $(X,\{A,B\},Y,\{C,D\})$ on one occasion, and $(Y,\{C,D\},X,\{A,B\})$ on another occasion, you are counting the same thing twice: the same boys got the same gifts.

Comment: OOOh awesome i just understood that perfectly. thanks you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach counts those arrangements in which fewer than eight children receive a toy.  Let's modify your approach accordingly.

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways of choosing two children to not receive a toy.  There are $8^{10}$ ways of distributing the ten toys among the remaining eight children since there are eight possible recipients for each of the ten toys.  However, this counts those distributions in which fewer than eight children receive a toy.  We must exclude those cases.

There are $\binom{8}{k}$ of excluding $k$ of those eight children from receiving a toy and $(8 - k)^{10}$ ways of distributing the ten toys to the remaining $8 - k$ children.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways of distributing the ten toys to exactly eight children is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{8} (-1)^k\binom{8}{k}(8 - k)^{10}$$
Hence, the number of ways of distributing the ten toys so that exactly two of the children do not receive a toy is 
$$\binom{10}{2}\sum_{k = 0}^{8} (-1)^k\binom{8}{k}(8 - k)^{10}$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  I had the same reaction.  When I tried to do the problem your way, I came to the same result as you did.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  You were correct.  My error was distributing recipients to toys rather than toys to recipients.  Our answers now agree.

Comment: Glad we finally agreed :) +1, and a nice alternative.

Comment: umm there are two things i didnt understand.firstly shouldnt no. of ways be 10^(8-k) because each of the children can get upto 10 toys and there are 8-k children. Secondly i didnt get how is this using the inclusion exclusion principle?

Comment: And why are you excluding children from the remaining 8? All the remaining 8 have to get atleast one toy right? Im super confused now

Comment: If we distribute the ten toys to $8 - k$ children, there are $8 - k$ possible recipients for each of the ten toys.  Hence, the number of ways of distributing the ten toys is $$\underbrace{(8 - k)(8 - k)(8 - k) \cdots (8 - k)}_{10~\text{factors}} = (8 - k)^{10}$$  The reason I am excluding children from the remaining $8$ is that $8^{10}$ counts all possible distributions of ten toys to eight children, including ones in which fewer than children receive a toy (like giving one child all the toys).  We want to count those distributions in which exactly eight children receive a toy.

Comment: Let me elaborate on why there are $8^{10}$ ways of distributing ten toys to eight children.  There are eight possible recipients for the first toy.  For each of the eight ways we can choose a child to receive that toy, there are eight ways to give the second toy to a child, so there are $8^2$ ways of distributing the first two toys.  Continuing in this way, we see that there are $8^{10}$ ways to distribute ten toys.

Answer (score 0):

I think we choose first two children which will not receive toys, then distribute 8 toys among the 8 remaining kids (there are $10\cdot 9 \cdots \cdot 3=10!/2!$ ways to do it) and finally we decide if choose one or two children for the remaining toys. So, the answer should be $$\binom{10}{2}\cdot \dfrac{10!}{2!}\cdot \left(\binom{8}{1}+\binom{8}{2}\right)$$

Comment: There are duplicates: the two remaining toys may also be distributed before, among the $8$. For example, distributing toys 1-8, then the 9 and 10 to the boys who got the 1 and 2, is equivalent to distributing the toys 3-10, then the 1 and 2.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You are right!